# QBox configuration error: unable to find "cc"

Tags: configuration, qemu

I am trying to build QBox

```
https://git.greensocs.com/qemu/qbox
```

For Configuration, I am using

```
./configure --target-list=arm-softmmu --library --qbox --with-tlm2c=/proj/user/tlm2c --prefix=/proj/user/Qbox --disable-pie --extra-cflags=--ftls-model=initial-exec
```

But I am getting the following error while configuration:

> ERROR: "cc" either does not exist or does not work

I tried to set the flag `--cc=gcc` but still getting the same error. I am using gcc version 4.7.2.

Answer (score 3):

It is missing gcc, so run the below command to resolve it

```
$ sudo apt-get install gcc
```